# how to establish security context for transactions done from spring amqp messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a spring boot application for which I secure methods using spring security annotations as shown below.

```
public interface UserService {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    List<User> findAllUsers();

    @PostAuthorize ("returnObject.type == authentication.name")
    User findById(int id);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    void updateUser(User user);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') AND hasRole('DBA')")
    void deleteUser(int id);

}
```

The problem that I have here is that there are implementations which are called via `@RabbitListener` methods which does not have any security context because it's not a web request.

I can expect the clients to pass the usernames via message headers sp I could use `message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().get("username")` to get the username for that request.

But still I believe there won't be a straightforward approach as the method level annotations won't be evaluated because they are not under security context.

Is there any approach via which I can establish a security context for a spring amqp messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the context...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class So49957413Application extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49957413Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("foo").password("bar").roles("baz");
    }

    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;


    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void listen(Message in) {
        try {
            SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
            ctx.setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(in.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().get("user"), "bar"));
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
            this.foo.method1();
            try {
                this.foo.method2();
            }
            catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
                System.out.println("Denied access to method2");
            }
        }
        finally {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    public static class Foo {

        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('baz')")
        public void method1() {
            System.out.println("in method1");
        }

        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('qux')")
        public void method2() {
            System.out.println("in method2");
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
in method1
Denied access to method2
```

It would be better to add/remove the security context in an advice, in the listener container's advice chain, to avoid mixing the security code with your listener logic.