# How to get Spring AMQP Message from Advice

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have 2 services Producer and Consumer.
In the service Consumer I have multiple places using SecurityContextHolder to get the current user.
Then I want to pass a User Id from Producer to Consumer when sending a message.

I follow the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49957948/6484502
but I don't know how to get the Message from Advice?

Could you please provide an example of that Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a `org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor`. The AMQP message is a second argument of the `MethodInvocation.getArguments()`. You cast it into a `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message`, take your `userId` and call `ctx.setAuthentication()` before `invocation.proceed()`.